# Unable to apply lifecycle policy on s3 bucket when prefix is nested

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have applied a lifecycle policy on s3 bucket name (`async-download`) with prefix `tmp_active_job_storage/`

This works as expected when prefix is immediately after bucket name.

Below is the object key:

```
https://async-download.s3.amazonaws.com/tmp_active_job_storage/file_name.png
```

[image: Lifecycle configuration]

But this is not working when I introduced one folder between the bucket name and prefix. Folder name before prefix is dynamic key I can't apply rule on it.

Now modified object key is:

```
https://async-download.s3.amazonaws.com/1111-2222-3333-4444/tmp_active_job_storage/file_name.png
```

In API documentation [PUT Bucket lifecycle - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html) I can not see any support for prefix as regex.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> *Folder name before prefix is...*

By definition, nothing can come "before" a key prefix.  The prefix is the beginning of the object key.  S3 lifecycle rules only support exact string matches, not regexes.

You need a common prefix at the beginning of all the object keys, or you need to dedicate a bucket to store these temporary files (and nothing else) so that the lifecycle policy can be applied to the entire bucket.